# Thunderbird: Mark all messages inside selected Folder(s) Unread

Tags: email, thunderbird, folder-redirection, move

Its possible to mark all messages as read in selected folder(s). It is useful for archival purpose.

But is it also possible to mark all messages of selected folder(s) as unread? It is useful for certain folders where I need to take action.

---

I have a list of favorite folders to which I move messages from various inbox, and I want them to me marked as unread after moving to destination favorite folders

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

I would create a search folder to find all messages and select the folders to search in. In this new view, press CTRL-A to select all messages and then mark them read, unread, assign a category to it, or anything else you want to do with your selection.

To create a search folder, right-click your local Folders, Search Messages. In the new window, at the bottom, press Save as Search Folder. You do not need to give any criteria for finding emails, although you can. For example, only search for emails that are x days old.

In the new popup, give it a name, and besides the folders, press Choose to select any folder from any account that you want to include. Double check that you have all the folders you want to search for and no more, no less.

Once added, a new search folder appears in your local folders. Click it and wait for all emails to be found.

Comment: I didn't wanted to create local folders as I want these to be synced over IMAP and available on various devices.

Comment: @Porcupine you are not creating a folder to store your emails. Its only a search you save to quickly find the emails in the future and perform the action again and again.

Comment: Thank you so much. So I created the search folder named "MarkUnread", it works as you described. Is it also possible to automatically mark all messages in this search folder as unread when i quit Thunderbird?

Comment: I don't know if that's possible. Maybe using message filters. So far I have not used search filters for what you want. I use them to keep all the mails I want to see all the time in one place. So instead of moving all mails to these folders, I keep them where they are and use search folders to put them all in one place. I do use filters to automatically mark messages read on receive and give them a star and my search folder shows starred messages. I unstar a message and it vanishes from my search folder, but no emailbox has unread mail counters.